# Can I detect older monitors and supply them with web-safe colours?

Tags: html, colors, web-safe-colors

I want to use non-web-safe colors in several places on my website, including for the background. But I am concerned about visitors with older computers.

Is there any code I can use that will change the color from the non-web-safe color to the nearest web-safe color if the visitor cannot see non-web-safe colors?

Comment: You can do this in JavaScript, but not, I think, with just html.

Comment: You could probably check color depth, but is it really worth it? How many users still have only 256 colors?

Comment: I seriously would not worry about this and *I* try to support everything. Like everyone else is saying, the web-safe color thing is from the 8-bit days, long ago. I just pulled up analytics on a site with 20,000 visits in the past month and there were 5 visits by 8-bit machines. This represents 0.025% of the visits and is just not worth dealing with. I'm guessing these were visits by people in a server room somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

As this question cannot, to my knowledge, be answered with simple HTML, I'm posting this JavaScript solution to offer an alternative means:

It's possible to use `screen.colorDepth` to return the color depth, in bits, of the user's screen. With the exception of a faulty/erroneous implementation in Firefox 3.x and 4.1 (beta).

```
var theImg = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

if (screen.colorDepth < 32) {
    theImg.src = 'http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/the_shat.png';
}
else {
    theImg.src = 'http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/terry_thomas.png';
}

alert(screen.colorDepth);
```

**Addenda** with respect to PPK, Chromium 11/Ubuntu 11.04 *also* returns `24` rather than `32`, so Firefox may have been correct.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/j4X7G/).

Reference:

- [W3C DOM compatibility - CSS Object Model View, PPK, Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t11).

Comment: Reading the W3C link you provided I found this under pixelDepth: "...colorDepth matches the color depth of the application and pixelDepth the color depth of the monitor. In all other cases they’re equal." So you may want to try to use pixelDepth first and colorDepth if pixelDepth doesn't exist

Comment: @Bryce, good catch. But just to be clear: that's a link to Quirksmode.org, *not* W3C... :)

Comment: Heh, yea. I was just referring to the W3C in the linked text.

Answer (score 1):

I may be mistaken here, but the point of web-safe colours was so that your images will look the same on a monitor with a lower colour depth (eg. 8-bit colour) as they would on one with a higher color depth (16/24-bit colour). Which would happen because all of those colours should (theoretically) be able to be displayed in all colour formats.

If you have an image that is not "web-safe", and you view it on a system with 8-bit colour, all of the colours that don't fit within the display's colour capabilities, should automatically be displayed as the closest colour that fits. Basically, you don't have to "convert" it. The bit depth of the colour doesn't allow it to display any OTHER colours and so it'll have to sub something in, which *should* be the next closest display colour.

That said, web-safe colours are from the time when displays only used 8-bit colour. I don't think that this is something you really have to worry about now unless you know that your audience is using very, very, old technology.

Answer (score 0):

The browser will automatically do this if your using hex/color codes and not images. And with images they will just dither, graceful degrading their experience with no work.

http://www.limov.com/colour/when-to-use-the-web-safe-palette.lml